# Dynamically posting properties to an API in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a service that can PUT a single field from a document back to the server

I have this:

```
updateProperty(field: string, value: string): Observable<Property> {
    return this.http.put<Property>(`${this.apiUrl}/property`, { field, value });
}
```

but when I call it with:

```
updateProperty("Name", "John")
```

It creates the following header:

```
field : "Name"
value : "John"
```

How can I change this so that the header becomes:

```
"Name" : "John"
```

**Update**
When I try { field : value } then the header becomes:

```
field: "John"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike what has been said here by my fellow developpers, you don't need to create a new object.

Use the dynamic key notation for objects :

```
updateProperty(field: string, value: string): Observable<Property> {
  return this.http.put<Property>(`${this.apiUrl}/property`, { [field]: value });
}
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gctme?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

That is related to how object destructuring works. `{field, value}` actually means `{field: field, value: value}`. To get what you want you'd have to create an object eg. `obj` and then construct it with `obj[field] = value`. And then pass it into your put request, replacing the currently specified `{field, value}`.

Answer (score 0):

any object can be parse as "array" syntax style :

```
const field = "name";
const value = "John";

const data = {};
data[field] = value;
console.log(data);
```

so you can do something like this :

```
updateProperty(field: string, value: string): Observable<Property> {
    let header = {};
    header[field] = value;
    return this.http.put<Property>(`${this.apiUrl}/property`, header);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to create a new object, you can do it in a single line like the OP did (feel free to check my answer, @RobbieMills)

Comment: nice @trichetriche i have never seen this syntax before, thx for your sharing.